# Passing argument to function component - typescript ts2322 error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an issue with typescript in the following simple component.

This works as expected:

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const simpleComp = (shouldSayA: boolean) => {
    return shouldSayA ? <p>a</p> : <p>b</p>;
  };

  return <div>{simpleComp(true)}</div>;
}
```

However, when I convert the simpleComp function to JSX function component SimpleComp like so:

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const SimpleComp = (shouldSayA: boolean) => {
    return shouldSayA ? <p>a</p> : <p>b</p>;
  };
  return <div><SimpleComp shouldSayA={true} /></div>;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
const SimpleComp: (shouldSayA: boolean) => JSX.Element
Type '{ shouldSayA: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & boolean'.
  Type '{ shouldSayA: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'true'.ts(2322)
```

I can fix the TS error doing something like this:

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const SimpleComp = ({shouldSayA}: { shouldSayA: boolean }) => {
    return shouldSayA ? <p>a</p> : <p>b</p>;
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <SimpleComp shouldSayA={true} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

but I'm sure there's some easier way that I'm missing.
Why does TS throws an error in the second example?

Answer (score 4):

The first argument passed to a component is the object containing **all** of the props.

If you pass one prop then it will be an object containing a single key:value pair.

That's just how components work. There is no simpler way.

---

That said, it is usually better to:

- Define your components once instead of redefining them on every render
- Define your type as a variable and not inline

```
import React from "react";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <SimpleComp shouldSayA={true} />
    </div>
  );
};

type SimpleCompProps = {
  shouldSayA: boolean;
};

const SimpleComp = ({ shouldSayA }: SimpleCompProps) => {
  return shouldSayA ? <p>a</p> : <p>b</p>;
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Hi, that's how I ended up doing in my actual code but still thought there would be a more straight-forward way of doing it to keep the structure somewhat similar to the way it works when this <SomeComp .../> component is used as a callable function someComp(true) within JSX. Thanks for your answer though.